# Movie recommender system: For every movie find the movie which the raters rated as well

Tags: python, dictionary, recommendation-engine

I have a nested dictionary of movie ratings:

{'John':{'Star Wars': 1.0,
'Silence': 2.0,
'Forrest' : 3.0},
'Maria':{'Star Wars': nan,
'Silence': 1.0,
'Forrest':2.0},
'Mike':{'Star Wars': 9.0,
'Silence': nan,
'Forrest':nan},

Now I would like to make a function which counts for every movie how many people who have seen that movie (score != nan) also watched the other movies and then order them by descending order.

I hope this is clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what is your expected output format,  you can customize the sample code (below) to suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This will be my approach to this ranking system:

```
from collections import defaultdict

nan = 0    # to simplify the parsing...

dc = {'John' :{'Star Wars': 1.0, 'Silence': 2.0, 'Forrest' : 3.0},
      'Maria':{'Star Wars': 0, 'Silence': 1.0, 'Forrest':2.0},
       'Mike':{'Star Wars': 9.0, 'Silence': 0, 'Forrest': 0}}
       
scores = defaultdict(int)

for name, movies in dc.items():
   
    for movie, score in movies.items():
        if score:       # not 0
            scores[movie] += score
    
print(scores)
ranking = {k: v for k, v in sorted(scores.items(),
                    key=lambda item: -item[1])}
print(ranking)    # {'Star Wars': 10.0, 'Forrest': 5.0, 'Silence': 3.0}
```

Comment: Please click the checkmark if this answer is helpful! Feel free to comment for further clarification!